# How to disassemble Pierburg electric fuel pump

Tags: mercedes-benz, fuel-pump

I've recently replaced my fuel pump on my W202. The one I replaced seems to be the one that was installed in the factory as it has the MB logo and is made by Pierburg. The new one is from Bosch. In fact, I replaced it because it was making some kind of high voltage noise in the car and now it's gone. What I want to do is disassemble the old pump and see what's inside and maybe try to fix it. But I can't figure out how to take off the outer metal shell. Has anybody been able to disassemble this kind of fuel pump? Here's how the fuel pump looks:

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post hi-res photos  from all sides?

Comment: Most likely the end of the metal shell is crimped/bend over the lids

Comment: I'd have to agree with @Myself here ... I doubt it is user serviceable. You'd most likely destroy the casing getting it apart. Then once inside, you'd find you couldn't get any parts to fix it. Just my gut check, though, so leaving this as a comment.

Comment: @Myself, I've added the photos

Comment: @Mikayil Maybe take out the screw on top?  It probably wasn't *designed* to be user servicable, but that doesn't mean that it's impossible.  Whatever you do, take pictures along the way so that you can post an answer here when you're done.  I'm interested to see where this goes!

Comment: Not an answer, but worn electric motor brushes are a primary cause for fuel pump failures

Comment: @Cullub, I've already tried what you suggested. That screw is just for holding the plastic cover over the two wire connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Opening:**

IMHO I think (not know) that the only method to open the pump is to carefully bend the fold open on top of the lid. Judging from the pictures I would work tangentially using a very small woodworking chisel (using the dull edge as lever point, facing inwards) to bend the crimp radially outwards (sharp edge touching the outer shell). Perhaps you can place some kind of collar (hose clamp) around the shell (just under the fold) to prevent warpage of the shell.

**Maintenance**

Normally there should be two o-rings inside that you need to replace. If only the motor brushes are consumed you should be able to improvise them by using some other brushes and grind them to size. If the pump blades or the commutator are consumed the pump is supposed to be finished.